# Emojis don't render over web

Tags: javascript, html

I am not sure if it is my code or web browser-related. I have opened 4 different browsers, firefox, chrome, ms edge, and Tor Browser. I have xampp running on my pc which can be accessed locally and externally. Tor browser accesses the web server externally whereas all the other 3 access it locally.
When sending emojis locally they render fine but looking on the Tor browser (externally) it does not render any emojis and just shows weird-looking boxes. If I send an emoji through my chat it can be seen fine on all browsers except on the Tor Browser. If I click on one of the weird looking boxes on the Tor Browser and send, on all 3 local browsers I can see the emojis fine. It has taken me many months to get the emoji picker to work properly with the help of members on stackoverflow only to find this issue. is this my code or a browser issue? this is part of my code which deals with the emoji picker.

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="bubble-container"></div>
</div>

<div class="emoji" onclick="javascript:smileySelect(event);">
  <span title="Happy Face">  </span>
  <span title="Grinning Face">  </span>
  <span title="Grinning Face with Smiling Eyes">  </span>
</div>

<div id="sendCtrls">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Your message here" id="text">
  <button id="myBtn" style="width: auto;"> Send </button>
  <span title="Emoji" onclick="javascript:smiliesSH();"> </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this question help? https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/16051/why-tor-browser-doesnt-recognize-many-emojis

Comment: Do you have <meta charset="UTF-8"> inside <head> in your html file?

Comment: @Andrej yes it is there

Comment: @Lionel Rowe I tried their solution but did not work, I think evolutionxbox maybe right and that it is a browser specific issue. It does seem that way to be honest